# Symfony entity field type with custom unselectable separators

Tags: forms, symfony, select, entity

Lets say I have an entity City which has cityName also has priority 1, 2 or 3. I need to create a select box with the cities ordered by priority (ascending) and also add a separator before priority changes. the list should look something like that:

```
---Big cities:
bigCity1
bigCity2
bigCity3
---Smaller cities:
smallerCity1
smallerCity2
smallerCity3
smallerCity4
---Smallest cities:
smallestCity1
smallestCity2
....
```

those separators starting with `---` shouldn't be selectable. 
currently my formType looks like that:

```
class SelectCityFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('city', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'MainBundle:City',
                'property' => 'city',
            ))
            ->add('Select', 'submit');
    }
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'selectCityForm';
    }
}
```

How do I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use optgroup tag [to group](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#group-by) cities by specified field. Just add `'group_by' => 'field_name'` option to the city field.